# How to create a base view controller

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiviewcontroller

I would like to have a `BaseViewController` that subclasses `UIViewController`, overrides one of it's methods, but also require it's subclasses to implement new ones.

My case is a bit more complex, but this simple case represents my problem:

My `BaseViewController` would override `viewWillAppear` to set it's title, but the title string would come from it's subclasses. I thought about some options, not sure if/which one of them is best.

1 - Class with error throwing methods (my current solution):

```
class BaseViewController: UIViewController {
  override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    title = getTitle()
  }

  func getTitle() -> String {
    fatalError("Unimplemented method")
  }
}
```

2 - Receive the title in constructor:

```
class BaseViewController: UIViewController {
  var myTitle: String!

  convenience init(title titleSent: String) {
    self.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    myTitle = sentTitle
  }

  override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    title = myTitle
  }
}
```

*Note that this options gets really bad if there's more parameters to send*

I thought that using `protocol` would be perfect, until I find out that (of course) protocols can't subclass a class.

Didn't anybody do anything like this before? I don't think so, please share your thoughts.

**Update**

I tried another way, but got stuck in a compiler error, would this ever work?

```
procotol BaseViewController {
  var myTitle: String { get }
}

extension BaseViewController where Self: UIViewController {
  override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    title = myTitle
  }
}
```

The compiler says `Method does not override any method from its superclass`.

Comment: You're going about it the wrong way. If you want to create base controller you need to override some behaviour of `UIViewController` so you can really benefit when subclass the base controller. You can't override `viewWillAppear` using extensions because you would end up with having 2 implementations of `viewWillAppear` calling each other. Do you get my point?

Comment: Not sure if I understand the exact sequence of calls, but I can imagine it may not work. You mean if I conform `MyVC` with `BaseVC` protocol and override `viewWillAppear` on it, both functions will call each other?

Comment: The point is the compiler won't even let you override `viewWillAppear` in extension because theres nothing to override. Override works for subclassing only

Comment: I prefer the first way.

Answer (score 7):

I usually create protocol in which I declare what would be nice to have in the controllers. Then I check in the base controller if it's actually implemented and if so, just use the values, like this:

```
protocol ControllerType {
    var navigationTitle: String { get }
}

extension ControllerType {
    var navigationTitle: String {
        return "Default title"
    }
}

class BaseViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        if let controller = self as? ControllerType {
            self.title = controller.navigationTitle
        }
    }
}

class ViewController: BaseViewController, ControllerType {

    var navigationTitle: String {
        return "ViewController"
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()    
    }
}
```

Downfall is you have to implement the `ControllerType` protocol and there's no way to enforce it.

Comment: Tha's nice, thanks for sharing. Not marking as accepted to see if anyone else found a better way

Answer (score 0):

Something similar would work.

```
class BaseViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() { }
    
    func setTitle(_ title: String) {
        self.title = title
    }
}

class ViewController: BaseViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()    
        self.setTitle("ViewController")
    }
}
```